# struts2: dynamic block page structure

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I want to render a list of complex objects on one page: tables, images, plots, etc. Each element will reside in its own block (for example `<div>`). There are several types of such complex objects so I don't want to implement rendering logic in one place, but rather modularize this somehow (separate JSP for each type of object as well as separate code, preparing data for JSP). What is the best way I can do this?

My own intend was to use `<s:action>` tag. So I could iterate over my list and invoke actions based on some condition:

```
<s:iterator value="objectList" var="element">
        <s:if test="#element.type == 'TABLE'">
            <s:action name="renderTable"><s:param name="elementValue" value="#element.value"/></s:action>
        </s:if>
        ...
</s:iterator>
```

Obviously in order to render table or plot or any other element I need to pass data to rendering action - you can see I'm trying to pass `entries` to my `renderTable` action. And here comes the problem - Struts casts this parameter to array of Strings and tries to find `setElementValue(String[])` in my action. So I get exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: edu.stackoverflow.RenderTable.setElementValue([Ljava.lang.String;)
```

I have no idea why the implementation of `org.apache.struts2.components.ActionComponent` handles parameters in such a way, here is the code from the class:

```
    for (Iterator i = parameters.entrySet().iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
        Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) i.next();
        String key = (String) entry.getKey();
        Object val = entry.getValue();
        if (val.getClass().isArray() && String.class == val.getClass().getComponentType()) {
            params.put(key, (String[])val);
        } else {
            params.put(key, new String[]{val.toString()});
        }
    }
```

So the approach becomes impossible.

Any alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use a normal JSP-based custom tag?

Alternatively, you could create a template-based component.

Comment: I'm not familiar with any of these approaches. Which one is simplest?

Comment: also for my rendering code I need to provide some dependencies via DI, so probably this will be difficult with JSP tags.

Comment: @pavel_kazlou Depends. The value stack is still available throughout the entire request, whether using custom tags, components, or using the action tag--this provides a number of ways to access values, including pushing values using `<s:push>`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that in place of template based component,creating custom tags in jsp is best way to go that will give you more control about handling the overall structure.

Alternatively you can create custom UI Component.

[creating_a_ui_component](http://www.vitarara.org/cms/struts_2_cookbook/creating_a_ui_component)

Comment: what if I need to pass to my rendering instance (be it a tag, a component, an action or whatever else) some dependencies? Can I create JSP tag or UI component and then use it inside Spring to inject dependencies?

Comment: i have not used it but i don't see any problem with that.say if you use action so you can ask Spring to create your action and pass on any dependencies.